# Comparing 2 columns Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

For the first table I am comparing both DrawNos and lengths, if they are same I am adding the quantites. If not write the exact column. The result table is right side. What is the excel formula for this?

Comment: formula would be IF/THEN/ELSE

Comment: can you explain more, i need excel formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sum column "quantity" by two key columns "draw No" and "length". Please follow these steps:

1. Copy your source table to another place (to the right).
2. Remove duplicates using the built-in Duplicate Remover tool by "draw No" and "length" columns.
3. In the 2d cell of the quantity column insert formula
   `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$11,$A$2:$A$11,$F2,$B$2:$B$11,$G2)` 
   (adjust references to your case) and copy it to all the cells in the quantity column

[image: =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$11,$A$2:$A$11,$F2,$B$2:$B$11,$G2)]

Comment: The result is the right table of the attached Picture and the questisn is: at the same time I want to compare DrwNo and Length with other row's DrwNo and length on the left table. If u cant see the pic; There are 3 rows A B and C; I want to copmpare first 2 row's(A1 ,B1) with other datas in this rows(A2 ,B2 and A3,B3 and ....) if same add the C data if not write that column.